# pymysql cursor fetch multiple rows

Tags: python, pymysql

I would like to show a list of users in groups of 2 from a database, I can get it to show the first two but then it returns to the main menu.  I would prefer if it scrolled through all the database, displaying two rows at a time rather than the first two rows only.  Where am I going wrong in my code, is it possible to put the fetchmany in a loop to run through all the users?

```
sql = ('Select * from user;')  
cursor.execute(sql)
data = cursor.fetchmany(size=2)
for row in data:
        print (row["userID"],":",  row["username"], ":", row["age"])
```

Comment: That's not sql code, best also tag whatever language it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDITED**:
You can use `fetchall` method to get a static list and iterate through it.

```py
sql = ('Select * from user;')  
cursor.execute(sql)
data = cursor.fetchall()
for i in range(0, len(data), 2):
    for row in data[i:i+2]:
        print(row["userID"],":",  row["username"], ":", row["age"])
    input()  # to display two rows per enter key press
```

Comment: That prints every user to the screen at the one time,  I forgot to mention in my original comment that only two rows should be displayed until any key is pressed then it would scroll to the next two users are shown and so on until the end of the list. But I appreciate the input.  its interesting to get a different look at things.

Comment: You can just add `input()` at the end of the outer for loop. Edited.

Comment: That worked perfectly.  Thank you.  Is it possible to leave the page before all the list has been displayed if it was too long? Could I display a Leave or Quit option after each two row display to bring me back to the main menu.

Comment: Maybe. I might need more information to answer that.